# Using TCSCConverter from the Word Interop in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I was trying to make a button that converts the selected text to traditional Chinese using

```
private void totradbutton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Word.Range currentRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
currentRange.TCSCConverter(Word.WdTCSCConverterDirection.wdTCSCConverterDirectionSCTC,true,true); 
}
```

however when the button is run on some selected text, the text is not changed to traditional Chinese. I have tried it on simplified, traditional, and a mixture and still nothing happens. I have put a message box in to check that the code is run, which it is. The return type of `TCSCConverter` is `void`, so it does not return a converted form.

The manual page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.tcscconverter.aspx does not seem to be too enlightening.

There doesn't seem to be any change to currentRange.text

Please can someone explain my mistake to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am unable to determine why it doesn't work, a work around is to use the `strConv` function in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` Assembly：

```
currentRange.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrConv(currentRange.Text, VbStrConv.TraditionalChinese);
```

This seems to work without problems for already converted text or paragraph breaks, though there may be other problems I have not spotted.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly if the character is in the word maths environment